# Sending table datas to Controller without using ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a table in view which is static in nature.I am trying to post data to Controller without using Jquery Ajax. Is it possible?How can I retrieve all these data in Action **"bulk_insert"**. I am able to send this bulk data to controller using jquery ajax but I am unable to send it directly.

My view :

```
@using entity_framework.Models
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="container">
<h1>Static data</h1>
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("bulk_insert", "Form", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "postForm" }))
    {
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Menu Item Id</td>
                    <td>Menu Item Name</td>
                    <td>Menu Qty</td>
                    <td>Menu Rate</td>
                    <td>Total</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>

                    <td><input type="hidden" name="menu_item_id[0]" value="1" /><span>1</span></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="menu_item_name[0]" value="chaumin" /><span>chaumin</span></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="data[0].rate" value="100" /><span>100</span></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="data[0].qty" value="2" /><span>2</span></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="data[0].total" value="200"><span>200</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td><input type="hidden" name="data[1].menu_item_id" value="2" /><span>2</span></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="data[1].menu_item_name" value="Mo:Mo" /><span>Mo:Mo</span></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="data[1].rate" value="100" /><span>100</span></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="data[1].qty" value="2" /><span>2</span></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="data[1].total" value="200"><span>200</span></td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
    }
</div>
```

I am just testing with static data right now,but I need to do it with dynamic data i.e, When a user clicks a button, a row gets added using javascript .So,I didn't use Htmlhelper. My model:

```
public class tabledata
{

    public int menu_item_id { get; set; }
    public string  menu_item_name { get; set; }
    public string rate { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know how can I get table datas from form but my Controller method:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult bulk_insert(IEnumerable<tabledata> data)
    {
       //How can I get table datas here

    }
```

Comment: What is your controller POST method and the model your trying to bind to? (and why are your not using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods to generate the correct `name` attributes for binding?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke sir I have edited my question

Comment: And what is the signature of the controller method (I assume `IEnumerable<tabledata>`)?. Your generating `name` attributes that do not relate to your model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's  what I meant sir.How can I retrieve these  data? I have no idea about it.

Comment: For the 3rd time - **show your controller method signature**

Comment: Your `name` attributes needs to be `name="[0].menu_item_id"`, `name="[0].rate"`, `name="[1].menu_item_id"`, `name="[1].rate"` etc. You should generate a view for 2 existing items using a `for` loop and inspect its html so you can see the correct html you need for binding

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry sir but I didn't get you. I meant to get the details shown in view to my Controller method

Comment: Just change the `name` attributes as per my last comment!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did sir.Could you please help me on controller method to put those data in datatable?

Comment: Just use a loop to iterate through the controller and add each item to the database

Comment: @StephenMuecke May be this is annoying for you but sorry to say I am not getting data in Ienumerable lists item.Could you please help me on this?

Comment: You will if your have changed the `name` attributes as per my previous comments. If your not then its dues to other code you have not shown or your collection indexers do not start at zero and are consecutive.